# For loop in `define Macro

Tags: verilog, hdl, user-defined-types, preprocessor-directive

I searched on SO, and on web, no where found the ans.
I have following code, where It success fully parsed `define and generate expected results, but if number of times calling of macro is large then, Can we using ***Looping Construct?***.

```
`define myreg(name) \
   addr_``name    

`define para(i) \
  parameter `myreg(i) = i  

module register;

`para(1);
`para(2);
`para(3);
`para(4);

initial
begin
  $display("ADDR1 = %d, ADDR2 = %d", addr_1, addr_2);
  $display("ADDR3 = %d, ADDR4 = %d", addr_3, addr_4);
  #100 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Simulation Result:

```
// # Loading work.register(fast)
// # run -all
// # ADDR1 =           1, ADDR2 =           2
// # ADDR3 =           3, ADDR4 =           4
// # ** Note: $finish    : reg.v(18)
```

Now, when I use ***for loop***, like in below code,

```
`define myreg(name) \
   addr_``name    

`define para(i) \
  parameter `myreg(i) = i  

module register;

genvar i;
generate 
  for (i = 1; i<=4; i=i+1)
  begin
    `para(i);
  end
endgenerate

initial
begin
  $display("ADDR1 = %d, ADDR2 = %d", addr_1, addr_2);
  $display("ADDR3 = %d, ADDR4 = %d", addr_3, addr_4);
  #100 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

In that case, It shows an error while displaying or using it,
Simulation Result:

```
// # vsim -lib work register -c -do "run -all; quit -f" -appendlog -l qverilog.log -vopt 
// # ** Note: (vsim-3813) Design is being optimized due to module recompilation...
// # ** Error (suppressible): (vopt-7063) reg.v(24): Failed to find 'addr_1' in hierarchical name '/addr_1'.
// # ** Error (suppressible): (vopt-7063) reg.v(24): Failed to find 'addr_2' in hierarchical name '/addr_2'.
// # ** Error (suppressible): (vopt-7063) reg.v(25): Failed to find 'addr_3' in hierarchical name '/addr_3'.
// # ** Error (suppressible): (vopt-7063) reg.v(25): Failed to find 'addr_4' in hierarchical name '/addr_4'.
// # Optimization failed
// # Error loading design
```

It is asked more times but proper solution is not given by any one, any help appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually much simpler than as sharvil111 explains.

The directives `` `define ``s, `` `ifdef ``s and `` `include ``s all get handled by a preprocessor that produces a stream of text and is fed into a compiler. The preprocessor does not know anything about Verilog syntax and the compiler does not see any of those directives because they have been processed away.

You can actually see this intermediate stream of text by adding the `vlog -E <filename>` option which writes the output of the preprocessor to

There is no looping directive in Verilog/SystemVerilog. Some options for you are:

- write the macros out by hand. Perhaps you can find some function in your text editor to help you do this
- use some other macro preprocessor to generate your code. This can make debugging difficult as you have to manage two sets of source code files.
- Restructure your code to use an array instead of having separately named parameters

Comment: "use some other macro preprocessor to generate your code. This can make debugging difficult as you have to manage two sets of source code files." Can you give any example or code?

Comment: Can you please tell me, how can I use that *vlog -E <filename>*?

Comment: It is listed in the Questa/ModelSim Reference Manual

Comment: I am not able to find that, can you please share that document link and page number?

Comment: Just type `vlog -help` or look in the help menu when you bring up the gui

Comment: I run command *vlog -E reg.v*, but it again shows help stuff.

Comment: thanks alot, I got usage of it, vlog filename.v - E output.v, where output.v contain define parsed file.

Answer (score 3):

For any simulation, following sequence of events takes place:

> Compilation Phase ==> Elaboration Phase ==> Run Phase (Simulation Phase)

At **compile time**, the **syntax error checking and macros text substitution** is performed. **Memory for all the variables** is calculated and an executable is build. During compile time, which a program's source code is being **translated** into **executable code**.

At **elaboration time**, the **instances** and **connection** between instances is formed. By connectivity, I mean **checking port widths** and **ports existence** etc. Since, the actual instances are created, **parameters** are also **evaluated** at elaboration time.

At **run time**, of course, the **actual simulation starts** running from zero time on wards.

Macros are evaluated at **compile time** (hence known as **compiler** directives), while `generate` block evaluates at **elaboration time**.

Referring to [IEEE 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), Section 27.3:

> Generate schemes are evaluated during **elaboration of the design**. 
>   ...
>   They are evaluated at elaboration time, and the **result is determined before simulation begins**. Therefore, **all expressions in generate schemes shall be constant expressions, deterministic at elaboration time**.

The first example runs because **everything is done at compile time**. All the variables are declared at compile time itself. Hence the code works fine.

In the second example, you are trying to ***declare variables*** at elaboration time which is not allowed. No more **memory to variables** is allocated at elaboration time.

Refer [IEEE 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) section 3.12 for more information on compilation and elaboration time.

Comment: Your explanation is perfect! I understood the concept, Now what should I do for second code? Is it possible to have repetition or "for" looping kind of thing in compile time?. Or It is not possible?

Comment: You have only a limited set of compiler directives, using `generate` loop is no way a solution. I'd prefer to use an **array** of variables controlled by parameter, like `parameter SIZE=5; reg [7:0] ADDR[SIZE];`. Or you can use some macro controlled array like `ifdef SIZE reg [7:0] ADDR[SIZE]; else define SIZE 5 ADDR[SIZE]; endif`. And provide `SIZE` as simulation switch like `+define+SIZE=5`. This will override the `SIZE` as per simulation switch.

Comment: Rather in comments, Can you please add it to answer?